# Monitoring per Application power usage in android

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the average current/power consumption of a particular application in Android? I could only find private API PowerProfile.java and PowerUsageSummary.java which give some information, but I am hitting a dead end, can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get the average current/power consumption of a particular application in Android?

No, because applications do not consume current/power. Hardware does. If six applications are using WiFi, it is very difficult to "assign blame" for the WiFi power consumption, for example.

Now, even getting hardware power information is difficult in Android, as there are no public APIs for it, and most hardware is not instrumented particularly well to indicate what is consuming power. The Qualcomm MDP has great instrumentation for this, along with Trepn software to help you collect it, but it is rather expensive.

Comment: I think there might be some private APIs to do it, I am referring to UsageStatsService, IUSageStats.aidl, and PkgUsageStats etc ,you may wanna take a look at these.

Comment: @MayurPandey: Those are not especially accurate, and, as you point out, they are not accessible to third-party applications (I have tried...).

Comment: hmmm, i guess you are right. I too tried a lot of ways to write code to access the said classes, but no avail !!!